# Java OOP: check if X or Y object is in Array[i], then print text

Tags: java, arrays, oop, indexing

I am trying to figure out how can I deal with arrays indexing using declared methods for fast list-editing, I thought of this self-example:

Let us say that I have a list of arrays with x and yn objects, I'd like to create two methods that search for the desired object in a specific index of the array and would change it and print an appropriate line, for example:

```
class Testing
public static void main(String[] args){
//The objects were created from a constructor from an other X class 
Object [] objectsList1 = {x,x,y1,x};
Object [] objectsList2 = {y2, y3, x, x};


//check if x exists in [k]objectsList1, if it does print 1, if it doesn't change it to desired yn and print2.
//check if not-x exists in [k]objectsList1, if it does print 3, if it doesn't change it to x and print4.
}
```

My thoughts were that I'd need 2 Boolean methods to check if x or y exist or not, with an if and else statement, then use these methods in changeX and changeY methods, but I am struggling with how could I declare the 4 methods and implement it because of the index.

```
Class ChangeNCheck;
//x is declared here and is static (could need to move yn objects here and declare them static?)
//define methods for this
public Boolean checkX(){}
public Boolean checkY(){}
changeX(){}
changeY(){}
```

Kindly show an example for the 4 cases in main, with appropriate declared methods in changeNCheck class.

EDIT:
The following if statement works for x and objectsList1:

```
if (x.equals(objectsList1[i]))
                System.out.println("4");
        else {
                objectsList1[i] = x;
                System.out.println("3");
        }
//same for yn
```

However, I can't bring myself to declare a method that does all of this to avoid repeatedly writing it everywhere.

EDIT 2: used proper conventions for array objectsListn.

Comment: What's the implementation of X and Y classes?

Comment: I'd like to use them for printing, I have several methods to deal with if a [i] index contains x or not (which changes a particular variable if true), and declared them using constructors (int z, String code).

Comment: Unrelated: please be much more careful when naming your variables. First of all `ArrayList` is a class from the java.util collection framework. Naming an **array** "ArrayListx" is **super** confusing for your readers. And: variable names go camelCase in java. They *never* start UpperCase!

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks! I fixed them. I really appreciate all tips on conventions as we weren't taught them except briefly in this apocalypse.

Comment: Can I ask why do you want two methods to check and change array elements? What I understand is that you need a method which checks if an element is present on a particular index of an array then you need to change that element. am I missing something? and one more question is the message you want to print same or changes according to the list?

Comment: I have a lot of Object lists where I need to change the values of list[i] for many of them. The message is the same one whatever the list is, but it is different if I'm starting from x or yn.
@VinitPillai

Comment: this can't be the answer but still i'm asking if this is what you want?

checkAndChange(String element, String[] array, int index){

if (element.equals(array[index]))
                System.out.println("your message");
else {
                array[index] = element;
                System.out.println("your Message");
        }
}

Comment: This is useful, thanks! 

@VinitPillai I am creating a small game where there are 'rooms' with people, and I am coding it according to the principal 'if x, it is by default empty, if yn, it has values'.

Comment: I'm writing this in answer. You don't have to accept it but at least do +1 if this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help...

```
public void checkAndChange(String element, String[] array, int index) {
            if (element.equals(array[index])) {
                System.out.println("your message");
            } else {
                array[index] = element;
                System.out.println("your Message");
            }
}
```